# What gets executed first? Is it script inside php tag or HTML?

Tags: php, csrf

I have a file with .php extension.
I am following a tutorial and it has both  and  in a same file.

So the file looks something like:

```
<?php


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</html>
```

I was wondering which gets executed first?

BTW, this is a sidetrack to this problem.
This particular file has to do with preventing CSRF attack.
Inside HTML, there is a PHP snippet that looks like

```
 <?php Token::generate() ?>
```

in one of the hidden text fields.
I am not sure why he put both front end and back end in one file.
Is this the necessity to do CSRF prevention?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP gets executed on the server side, HTML will get interpreted on the client side. So which comes first?

Comment: From a security standpoint it is irrelevant how the code is broken into pieces and sections, as longs as it is glued together correctly. But if you put this html markup and that php code into separate files you will need a _third_ file to glue them together. Or, alternatively, some engine magic on the level of the php or the http level.

Comment: @arkascha - In my crude observation, sometimes HTML gets executed first and sometimes PHP gets executed first.  This really confuses me.  From my basic understanding of prevention of CSRF, it checks the  token value from the form  with what is kept in $_SESSION['token'] (in case, I store token value into this.)  So my limited logic tells me that it shouldn't matter to break it up into separate files.  I don't understand why you need 3rd file to glue it up?

Comment: @Nguaial your "crude observation" is wrong. When a request is made to a PHP script, that script is executed on the server, and the output (typically HTML, but sometimes JSON or something else) is then sent back to the browser. If the output includes `<script>` tags, those scripts will be executed by the browser only then. But there is no way that HTML, or anything inside it, can be executed "before PHP", because the HTML is only produced when the PHP script is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP gets executed on the server, output of this execution is a HTML code.

The browser takes the HTML code and displays it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great diagram.  That is great!  I understand the embedded php code within the HTML. My question is different.  This is the case when there are 2 sections: top section is <?php  ?> and the bottom section <html></html>.

Comment: @Nguaial that "case" is no different. The PHP script is executed, then the HTML output sent to the browser. The fact that some of the script is pure html outside of all PHP tags is irrelevant, that's still part of the output of the script which isn't sent to the browser until it's finished executing.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond - Thanks for clarifying this.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the execution is based on the order written in the file. Since PHP is on the top, PHP gets executed first.